# Redirect Woocommerce product to Post Object(Relational Field) ACF

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

my code is not working with this add_action in functions.php. I want to redirect the visitor to the associated page in Post Object ACF.

```
add_action( 'init', 'product_redirection_to_video' );
function product_redirection_to_video() { 

    if ( ! is_product() ) {
        // return; // Only for single product pages.
        $queried_object = get_queried_object();
        $post_id = $queried_object->ID;

        if( get_field('videomovie_link', $post_id) ) {
            $url = get_field('videomovie_link', $post_id) . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

            wp_redirect($url, 200);
            exit;
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Try to use `template_redirect` hook instead… also use `get_quiered_object_id()` for the product id, or `get_the_id()`… why are you using: `if( ! is_product() ) {`… Strange…

Comment: what my goal in here is every visit to the single product page it will be redirected to the post object acf. Thanks for recommendation